# Painting with combined textures - select texture section to use

Tags: texture-painting

I have a combined texture (see image inside red box)
[image]

Now I know how to paint with just a single texture, however I am totally confused about selecting say the grass from the upper left of the combined texture. I know in many other applications you crop at min and max to define an area of the combined texture to be used, however it does not seem to be working here :\
I have google my head off and usually I find stuff really quick but apparently I do not know the correct terminology for what I am looking for as "Blender Using Combined Textures" fails to return anything useful other than "combining multiple textures into one"
So if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. I am usually good at this type of stuff but blender has baked my noodle more than once in this endeavor :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your UV unwrapping needs to coincide with the image texture you are using. I would select the faces that need to be using a square of the image texture and Unwrap and then Reset, so that they are overlapped squares and with those selected in the UV Image Editor, scale and rotate to place them over the desired image portion - repeating the process until the unwrap is using the image the way you intend.